# Which trigger is starting a callback in Worklight geofencing?

Tags: location, ibm-mobilefirst, geofencing

Im using Worklight geofence APIs for defining a geofence circle as follows:

```
var Cliente ={
                type: "Enter",
                circle: {
                  longitude: vector[i].longitud,
                  latitude: vector[i].latitud,
                  radius: proximidad // 300m
                },
                confidenceLevel: "high", // ~95% confidence that we are in the circle
                callback: function(deviceCtx) { myFunction(deviceCtx); },
                eventToTransmit: {
                  event: {
                    name: "clientecerca",

                  },
                  transmitImmediately: true
                }
              };
```

How can I get some information about which trigger is running the callback? I need to display the information for that geofence in the app once the callback is called...

Answer (score 0):

As per you code you have mentioned a call back method. So this

```
 callback: function(deviceCtx) { myFunction(deviceCtx); },
```

Will be executed once geofence triggered. So in this function you define your code to display what you want.